# hash for auto generated ids not working on page load

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, anchor

in a current project i have different articles containing different headings (`<h3>`). Because the articles are composed in a CMS we cannot set the `id` of the `<h3>` element from the beginning on. Thats why I'm setting them on page load:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  let articleContent = $(".article-body")
  let headings = articleContent.find("h3")

  headings.each(function() {
    $(this).attr("id", $(this).first().text().replace(/\s/g, "-"))
  }
}
```

The problem is, when I try top open the URL with the given id of the heading as its hash to navigate the user to the right heading (eg. https://test.com/article-122321#heading2), this is not working. I guess this is the case because on page load the headings do not have any ids set and the browser doesn't know where to navigate to.

Can you help out with a solution for that? Do I have to set the ids at another point of time or do I need some custom Javascript code to tell the browser to navigate to the heading?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a try of this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".article-body h3").each(function() {
    $(this).attr("id", $(this).first().text().replace(/\s/g, "-"))
  })
  const hash = location.hash;
  const $element = hash ? $(hash) || null; // assuming a valid selector in the hash
  if ($element) $element[0].scrollIntoView({ // use the DOM method
    behavior: "smooth", // or "auto" or "instant"
    block: "start" // or "end"
  });
});
```

Comment: Might be a good idea to add some safety checks though. The hash might be empty, or there might be no element with a matching id (links from the outside, not under your control), and in that case you’d get some errors here.

Comment: @CBroe Okeyyy. If the code worked on their example and not on all, then I would say it's up to them to test. I do not  normally answer SO questions with 100% production ready code. Anyway see update

Comment: Fair enough, just saying, because this is a place with error potential that can easily get overlooked. For example a hash value that does not constitute a valid CSS selector to begin with, can also lead to errors here.

Comment: I could also do a try/catch on a URL object too to handle hashes that are invalid selectors